# Zend_Acl find all inherited roles

Tags: php, zend-framework, inheritance, roles, zend-acl

I got chain of roles:

```
acl.roles.guest  = null
acl.roles.member = "guest"
acl.roles.admin  = "member"
acl.roles.owner  = "admin"
```

in .....Controller/Action/Helper/Acl.php I have stored _acl object

Is it a way to get list of my role and parents ?

```
$this->_acl->getParents ( 'admin' )
```

should return

```
admin, member, guest
```

as array, or string (eg comma delimited)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

- `getRoles()` - *Returns an array of registered roles.*

and then check each of these with

- `inheritsRole()` - *Returns true if and only if $role inherits from $inherit*

See the API docs `Zend_Acl` at http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Acl/Zend_Acl.html

#### Example

```
$parents = array();
foreach ($acl->getRoles() as $inherit) {
    if ($acl->inheritsRole('owner', $inherit)) {
        $parents[] = $inherit;
    }
}
```

which would then return something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => guest
    [1] => member
    [2] => admin
)
```

---

### Alternative

There actually *is* a `getParents()` method in `Zend_Acl_Role_Registry`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to access that through the public interface of `Zend_Acl`. See the sourcecode

- http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Acl/Role/Registry.php

It is trivial to extend `Zend_Acl` to have a method `getParentsForRole()` though:

```
class My_Acl extends Zend_Acl
{
    public function getParentsForRole($role)
    {
        return $this->_getRoleRegistry()->getParents($role);
    }
}
```

This does only return the immediate parents though, e.g. for 'owner' it returns 'admin', so you might want to add another method to fetch all the parents recursively down to the last one:

```
class My_Acl extends Zend_Acl
{
    public function getAllParentsForRole($role, $parents = array())
    {
        foreach ($this->getParentsForRole($role) as $parentName => $parentRole) {
            if (FALSE === isset($parents[$parentName])) {
                $parents[$parentName] = $parentRole;
                $parents = $this->getAllParentsForRole($parentRole, $parents);
            }
        }
        return $parents;
    }

    public function getParentsForRole($role)
    {
        return $this->_getRoleRegistry()->getParents($role);
    }
}
```

#### Example

```
$acl = new My_Acl;
$acl->addRole('guest');
$acl->addRole('other');
$acl->addRole('member', 'guest');
$acl->addRole('admin', 'member');
$acl->addRole('owner', array('admin', 'other'));

print_r($acl->getAllParentsForRole('owner'));
```

would result in

```
Array
(
    [admin] => Zend_Acl_Role Object
        (
            [_roleId:protected] => admin
        )

    [member] => Zend_Acl_Role Object
        (
            [_roleId:protected] => member
        )

    [guest] => Zend_Acl_Role Object
        (
            [_roleId:protected] => guest
        )

    [other] => Zend_Acl_Role Object
        (
            [_roleId:protected] => other
        )    
)
```

which is in accordance with what a single call to `getParents` would return. If you dont need that, you can also just use the foreach code from the first example, e.g.

```
class My_Acl extends Zend_Acl
{
    public function getAllParentsForRole($role)
    {
        $parents = array();
        foreach ($this->getRoles() as $inherit) {
            if($this->inheritsRole($role, $inherit)) {
                $parents[] = $inherit;
            }
        }
        return $parents;
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW, WOW, WOW - I did not expect such complex answer and offcourse everything works as planned - I prefer second solution where looping thru getRoles() - THANK YOU